# what is minSdkVersion used for?

Tags: android, android-emulator

About the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`,I make a test like this: I only installed `android-15` in my eclipse, and I set `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"`(Notice it's `7`) In my app, I make a network connection in `Handler`, `it will not throw NetworkOnMainThreadException`;
But when I change to `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"`,exception happened! But I have no android-7, I thought Android-15 will be used.
BTW,`AVD is Android 4.0.3`

Question: `Does android-15 contain android-7 ?`

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if it answers your question. I see that you have asked 7 questions, including 6 upon which you received an answer for, but you never accepted even one as an answer to your question. It is the least you can do when someboy takes the trouble to give you an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes. If you program against SDK version 15, all features of SDK version 7 are also included.

The minSdkVersion is used to tell the Google Play Store which Android version is at least required to install your app.

You should use `targetSdkVersion` to say which version of the API you are using to program:

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Answer (score 1):

**android:minSdkVersion**

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

For more info click [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)